# jQuery: apply CSS to created node

Tags: jquery, css

I want to create HTML node, and then apply CSS style. With a simple element it is easy:

```
$('<div>').css("color","red")
```

In my case I want to insert a more complicated element, like:

```
<div id="foo">
  <span class="bar"> foo </span>
  <span class="baz"> bar </span>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
#foo {                                                                       
  ...                                                                        
}                                                                            

#foo .bar {                                                                  
  ...                                                                        
}                                                                            

#foo .baz {                                                                  
  ...                                                                        
}
```

I don't want to HTML code and styles separately for each node. I would like just to store HTML and the whole CSS in two strings, and create the node using those strings. Ideally, something like that:

```
html_blob = '<div> id="foo"> ... </div>'
css_blob = '#foo {... } ... #foo .baz {...}'

new_element = $(html_blob).apply_css_from_string(css_blob)
```

I build an extension using [Crossrider](http://crossrider.com/) and I need to create a popup dynamically.

Comment: @adeneo looked at the [jQuery constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) and didn't see a mention of this

Comment: @adeneo then you misunderstood the question. He wants to apply some CSS rules to a newly created DOM element tree (not just one element)

Comment: @JanDvorak - actually I did'nt, but my opinion is that it's better to create elements that way than to just have two long strings, one that according to the answers below should be inserted as a style tag into the head. here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PrRRk/) ?

Comment: @adeneo not always applicable. The two strings may come from a database, for example.

Comment: @adeneo I still agree it might be better when possible.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I give up ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$(someelement).append(html_blob);
$('head').append('<style id="tempstyle">' + css_blob + '</style>');
```

If you want to remove it later:

```
$('#tempstyle').remove();
```

Comment: Can I remove this style somehow when I hide the popup?

Comment: This could spill the style to other elements as well. Still a good solution with some preconditions.

Comment: @JakubM. just remove the `<style>` element

Comment: @JanDvorak Not if you write your selectors well.

Comment: @Asad That's what I mean by "preconditions".

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer with what I have understood :

```
 $("#top_element").append(html_blob);
```

Now, better if the css is present in the stylesheet before itself , or you can do like below to append dynamically :

```
$("head").append("<style>"+css_blog+"</style>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you would want to do this, or I am not getting what you want to achieve.

However if you need control over rendering repeating html controls. have a look at jQuery Templates.

[jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/) provides excellent control over repeating html content.

```
// Convert the markup string into a named template
// you can declare your string template like this
$.template( "summaryTemplate", "<li>${Name}</li>" );

function renderList() {
    // Render the movies data using the named template: "summaryTemplate"
    $.tmpl( "summaryTemplate", movies ).appendTo( "#moviesList" );
}
```